# Applying CIFiler to a masked portion of an image

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-image, cifilter

I'm looking for a way to apply a CIFilter to a portion of an image defined by a mask. Something like this, given an image:

[Source http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/213/browserpreviewtmp1p.jpg](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/213/browserpreviewtmp1p.jpg)

And a mask:

[image: Mask]

I apply some variation of

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,@"inputSaturation", @0, @"inputContrast", @1, @"inputBrightness", @0, nil];
```

And get this:

[Result http://imageshack.us/a/img689/5297/browserpreviewtmpd.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img689/5297/browserpreviewtmpd.jpg)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use another couple `CIFilter`s! You can take the top image and multiply it by the mask using [`CIMultiplyBlendMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346), then add it to the bottom image using [`CIAdditionCompositing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346).