# Apply a filter to only a portion of an image using a CIFilter

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cifilter

I am writing a photo editing app in Objective C and I would like to include a feature where the user can apply different filters to different parts of a photo. I know how to apply filters to the entire photo but I haven't found a way to apply that filter to only one part of the photo. This question is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999751/applying-cifiler-to-a-masked-portion-of-an-image) except using a mask would not work since the filter could be applied anywhere on the photo depending on the user, and I need an answer that will work with all types of filters provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Just a thought, perhaps you could create a new `UIImage` from a `CGRect`, apply the filter, then place the filtered image back onto the original image in the same spot.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but do you think it would take up too much time? I want this feature to be seamless and i think that creating an UIImage, applying the filter, and putting it back to the original image would take too much time and applying many filters to one photo would be a huge pain in the neck because you would have to wait each time a new filter is applied.

Comment: Not sure.  Only one way to find out...

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot...

Comment: The CG APIs for copying and rendering images into graphics contexts are pretty fast. It's quite likely that your filter will take longer to process than the pixel copies.